# javascript inside an eternal loop php code doesnt work

Tags: javascript, php

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <object width="100%" 
                    height="100%" 
                    id="liveTV_api" 
                    name="liveTV_api" 
                    data="http://www.extratv.gr/media/imgs/flowplayer-3.2.15.swf"    type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
               <param name="allowfullscreen" 
                      value="true">
               <param name="allowscriptaccess" 
                      value="always">
               <param name="quality" 
                      value="high">
               <param name="bgcolor" 
                      value="#000000">
               <param name="flashvars" 
                      value="config={&quot;clip&quot;:{&quot;url&quot;:&quot;mpegts_256.stream&quot;,&quot;provider&quot;:&quot;rtmp&quot;,&quot;live&quot;:true,&quot;scaling&quot;:&quot;fit&quot;},&quot;plugins&quot;:{&quot;rtmp&quot;:{&quot;url&quot;:&quot;http://www.extratv.gr/media/imgs/flowplayer.rtmp-3.2.11.swf&quot;,&quot;netConnectionUrl&quot;:&quot;rtmp://213.16.167.186:1935/live&quot;,&quot;subscribe&quot;:true}},&quot;playerId&quot;:&quot;liveTV&quot;,&quot;playlist&quot;:[{&quot;url&quot;:&quot;mpegts_256.stream&quot;,&quot;provider&quot;:&quot;rtmp&quot;,&quot;live&quot;:true,&quot;scaling&quot;:&quot;fit&quot;}]}">
            </object>
            <img id="adtv" src="img.png">
      </div>
<?php
set_time_limit(0);
$x=1;
while(x==1) {
   $now = date('G',time());
   $start = 12;
   $end = 13;

  if($now >= $start && $now <= $end):
     echo '<script type="text/javascript">document.getElementById("adtv").style.display="none"; </script>';
     echo '<script type="text/javascript">document.getElementById("liveTV_api").style.display="block"; document.getElementById("adtv").style.display="none";</script>';

   else:
     echo '<script type="text/javascript">document.getElementById("adtv").style.display="block"; document.getElementById("liveTV_api").style.display="none";</script>';
   endif;

   sleep(3600);
}

?>

    </body>
</html>
```

Ok i need a program that for 1 hr inside the day gonna show a video of 1 hr length and after that for the next 23 hrs gonna display an image.
Video is working perfect but the image is shown also instead of being hidden while the video div is active. seems that js doesnt work at all and i dont know why.

Comment: PHP runs on the server. Javascript runs on the client. What you want is essentially impossible.

Comment: browsers are waiting for a server response... An infinite loop here would probably give a timeout. Remove your loop and make a client (javascript) refresh at the top of the hour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use only Javascript, I haven't tested it:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<object width="100%" height="100%" id="liveTV_api" name="liveTV_api" 
data="http://www.extratv.gr/media/imgs/flowplayer-3.2.15.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"><param 
name="allowfullscreen" value="true"><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"><param name="quality" 
value="high"><param name="bgcolor" value="#000000"><param name="flashvars" value="config={&quot;clip&quot;:{&quot;url&quot;:&quot;mpegts_256.stream&quot;,&quot;provider&quot;:&quot;rtmp&quot;,&quot;live&quot;:true,&quot;scaling&quot;:&quot;fit&quot;},&quot;plugins&quot;:{&quot;rtmp&quot;:{&quot;url&quot;:&quot;http://www.extratv.gr/media/imgs/flowplayer.rtmp-3.2.11.swf&quot;,&quot;netConnectionUrl&quot;:&quot;rtmp://213.16.167.186:1935/live&quot;,&quot;subscribe&quot;:true}},&quot;playerId&quot;:&quot;liveTV&quot;,&quot;playlist&quot;:[{&quot;url&quot;:&quot;mpegts_256.stream&quot;,&quot;provider&quot;:&quot;rtmp&quot;,&quot;live&quot;:true,&quot;scaling&quot;:&quot;fit&quot;}]}"></object>
<img id="adtv" src="img.png">
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

function update() {
    var now = (new Date()).getHours(),
      start = 12,
      end = 13;

    if(now >= start && now <= end) {
        document.getElementById("adtv").style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("liveTV_api").style.display="block";
    }
     else {
        document.getElementById("adtv").style.display="block";
        document.getElementById("liveTV_api").style.display="none";
    }
}

// repeat interval in milliseconds
window.setInterval(update, 3600000);

update();

</script>

</body>
</html>
```